# Зачем делать инициализацию базы данных перед миграцией?

Tags: flask, миграция, flask-sqlalchemy

Для чего служит эта строчка кода?

```
db.init_app(app)
```

при запуске приложения?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.init_app(app)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Впервые встретилось при попытке сделать миграцию. Говорят, что это нужно для инициализации базы данных. Но раньше, у меня создавалась БД без этого.

Comment: Метод init_app вешает обработчик teardown для того, чтобы освобождать соединения при выходе из контекста приложения, и в документации к этой функции написано, что без init_app может случиться утечка памяти

Comment: Спасибо. Я пока в этом плохо разбираюсь. Мне удалось сделать миграцию без init_app.